# How can I get a list of icons currently in the Mac Menu bar?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, menubar, appkit

I'd like to get access to the icons that are currently in the Mac Menu Bar but I'm having trouble finding the relevant API's and classes.  I've looked at [NSStatusBar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsstatusbar) (which represents the MenuBar), but it does not provide any public access to what menu bar apps it contains.  I've also looked at [NSStatusItem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsstatusitem) and [NSStatusBarButton](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsstatusbarbutton), which represent items in the menubar and their visual representations, respectively, but everything I found about them is about making your own.

How can I programmatically learn what icons are in the mac menu bar, and what applications they correspond to?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functions available in CoreGraphics:

```
let windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo([.optionOnScreenOnly], kCGNullWindowID) as! [[String: Any]]

for window in windowList {
    let boundsDict = window[kCGWindowBounds as String] as! CFDictionary
    let applicationName = window[kCGWindowOwnerName as String] as! String
    let windowName = window[kCGWindowName as String] as! String

    if let bounds = CGRect(dictionaryRepresentation: boundsDict), bounds.origin.y == 0 {
        print(applicationName, windowName, bounds)
    }
}
```

During testing, I found that status bar items are those whose bounds stick to the very top of the screen. Not tested on multiple-screen setup though. Despite all this, all you can get is the name of the application owning the status bar item. I haven't found a way to create an instance of `NSStatusItem` that reference the item on the bar.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API which directly exposes this information.

You may be able to guess at it using the Accessibility API, by searching for objects which are positioned within the menubar (y=0) and getting the owner of each one. However, this will require your application to have Accessibility rights, which the user must explicitly enable in System Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
CFArrayRef aList = CGWindowListCreate(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly|kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID);
CFArrayRef aWindowsInfoArray = CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray(aList);
```

Filter the list by size and coordinates. kCGWindowOwnerName will contain the application's name.